# Fourier series for $f(x)=e^{3|x|}$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, fourier-series

I wish to find the Fourier series for $f(x)=e^{3|x|}$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$.

My solution: $f(x)$ is an even function so the $b_n$ coefficients are zero. As such we need only find $a_n$ and $\frac{a_0}{2}$. Using the usual formulae for these coefficients, I found the following:

$$S(x)=\frac{e^{3\pi}-2}{3\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{6e^{3\pi}(-1)^n-3-3e^{3\pi}(n^2+9)}{n^2+9}\cos(nx)$$

I do not think my solution for $\frac{a_0}{2}$ is correct ; apart from this, is the remainder of the solution correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to $\frac{a_{0}}{2}$ we get:

$$ a_{0}= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{- \pi}^{0} e^{-3x} dx + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{3x} dx = \frac{2}{3\pi} ( e^{3 \pi}-1)$$

Therefore, $$\frac{a_{0}}{2}= \frac{1}{3\pi} ( e^{3 \pi}-1)$$

So you might want to double-check how you computed those integrals.

Now, when it comes to the coefficients for the cosine series, we have:

$$ a_{n}= \int_{-\pi}^{0} e^{-3x}\cos(nx)dx + \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{3x}\cos(nx)dx$$

When you work this out you get:

$$ \frac{3(-1)^ne^{3\pi}-3} {n^2+9} + \frac{3(-1)^ne^{3\pi}-3} {n^2+9}=\frac{6(-1)^ne^{3\pi}-6} {n^2+9}  $$

Thus, your Fourier series should look like this:

---

$$ \frac{1}{3\pi} ( e^{3 \pi}-1) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{6(-1)^ne^{3\pi}-6} {n^2+9} 
 \cos(nx)$$

---

*Please remember to accept the answer if it is helpful.*